# не работает innerHTML в setInterval и setTimeout + setTimeout в setInterval

Tags: javascript, html

пытаюсь написать код, чтобы при нажатии менялся текст у тега `<span>`, но почему-то выскакивает ошибка

> 16index.html:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="txt" style="text-align:center;">подсвеченный текст<span id="spn"> </span></h1>
  <hr>
  <input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="узнать прямо сейчас!" style="left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, 0);position:absolute;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    var txt = document.querySelector("#txt");
    var spn = document.querySelector("#spn");
    var kar = "цвет";
    var kar1 = " синий";
    var kar2 = " красный";
    var kar3 = " жёлтый";
    var kar4 = " зелёный";
    var kar5 = " оранжевый";
    btn.onclick = () => {
      btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
      setInterval(function() {
        txt.innerHTML = kar;
        setTimeout(function() {
          spn.innerHTML = kar1;
          setTimeout(function() {
            spn.innerHTML = kar2;
            setTimeout(function() {
              spn.innerHTML = kar3;
              setTimeout(function() {
                spn.innerHTML = kar4;
                setTimeout(function() {
                  spn.innerHTML = kar5;
                }, 500);
              }, 500);
            }, 500);
          }, 500);
        }, 0);
      }, 3000);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

то есть каждые пол секунды должен меняться текст, разделил на 2 тега так как хочу потом сделать смену цвета шрифтов 2 слова, но это позже, я хочу заранее спросить, будут ли работать все `setTimeout` так, как задумано **(задумка: сработал 1 таймаут, через пол секунды после завершения одного таймаута начинает работать другой, и так 5 таймаутов, после того как сыграют все таймауты сыграет свою роль `setInterval` и начнётся отсчёт таймаутов заново и так этот интервал будет длиться без остановки)** или мне стоит все таймауты писать отдельно, а цифры до начала исполнения каждого таймаута складывать? (и да, я знаю то я мог положить все эти *kar* в массив, но мне так удобнее управлять данными), заранее спасибо!

Comment: А где у вас элемент #txt ?

Comment: исправил #txt, но теперь он только видит интервал, а таймауты внутри него - нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этой строчкой

```
txt.innerHTML = kar;
```

Вы удаляете все, что было внутри `<h1 id="txt"></h1>`. И хотя ссылка на элемент `<span id="spn">` у Вас есть, на странице этот элемент теперь отсутствует.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;"><span id="txt">подсвеченный текст</span><span id="spn"> </span></h1>
  <hr>
  <input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="узнать прямо сейчас!" style="left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, 0);position:absolute;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    var txt = document.querySelector("#txt");
    var spn = document.querySelector("#spn");
    var colors = [" синий", " красный", " жёлтый", " оранжевый"];
    var index = 0;
    var timer;
    btn.onclick = () => {
      btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
      txt.textContent = "цвет";
      timer = setInterval(function() {
        spn.textContent = colors[index];
        index = ++index % colors.length;
      }, 500);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, чего именно хотел добиться автор. Я бы сделал вот так.

```js
let цвета = [
['#F44336','красный',3000],
['#E91E63','розовый',5000],
['#9C27B0','пурпур',7000],
['#673AB7','глубокий пурпур',4000],
['#3F51B5','индиго',2000],
['#2196F3','голубой',6000],
['#03A9F4','светло-голубой',4000],
['#00ACC1','циановый',5000],
['#009688','чирок',7000],
['#43A047','зеленый',2000],
['#558B2F','светло-зеленый',1000],
['#827717','лаймовый',2000],
['#F57F17','желтый',3000],
['#E65100','оранжевый',6000],
['#F4511E','глубокий оранжевый',4000],
['#795548','коричневый',3000],
['#757575','серый',1000],
['#546E7A','голубо-серый',2000],
];

const ждать = миллисекунд => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,миллисекунд));
button.onclick = async () => {
  // Перемешаем рандомно
  цвета.sort(()=>Math.sign(Math.random()-.5));
  // Убираем кнопку
  button.style.display = 'none';
  let индекс = -1;
  // Бесконечный цикл
  while(1){
    индекс = ++индекс % цвета.length;
    let [ цвет, название, миллисекунд ] = цвета[индекс];
    // Ожидаем кадр
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
      // Цвет фона
      document.body.style.background = цвет;
      // Надпись
      message.innerHTML = название;
    });
    // Таймаут
    await ждать(миллисекунд);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  transition: all 1000ms;
  text-align: center;
}

#message, #button {
  height: 20vh;
  top: 40vh;
  font-size: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
}

#message {
  width: 80vw;
  left: 10vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1vh #000;
}

#button {
  width: 50vw;
  left: 25vw;
  border: 1vw solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="button">Нажми</div>
```